# Find all instances of $variables in single-quoted strings?

Tags: php, regex, string, phpstorm

Someone has made a change to the repo replacing all or most instances of `"` with `'` to assign strings. This has had the unintended effect of breaking many strings that are parsing variables. Examples:

```
$query = 'ALTER TABLE ' . $items . ' ADD `user_$name`';

$query .= '($length)';

etc.
```

Obviously this is breaking SQL queries, but it may not be limited to just strings assigned to `$query`.

Is there a regex or some function of PhpStorm that I can use to find all instances of this and fix them, either by reverting back to `"` or using `'` with concatenation?

Comment: Best fix is to find out who checked in the commit and make them go through every line of code and fix it manually as a just punishment.  Then when they are finished, roll back the repo and then make them rewrite all the code from subsequent commits and check those in to bring it back to current.  After that, fire them.

Comment: Hahah -- well luckily it wasn't on production and most instances *were* originally caught and manually fixed in the first place. I just ran into a couple in one file and want to go through make sure they're not elsewhere throughout the whole codebase.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find single-quoted string literals containing a `$`. The obvious thing to try would be this:

```
/'[^'$]*[$][^']*'/
```

That should find any single-quoted string containing a `$`. Unfortunately that doesn't quite work, since there may be backslash-escaped characters. So this is slightly better:

```
/'(?:[^'$]|\\.)*[$](?:[^']|\\.)*'/
```

But another problem is that there might be more than you might have something like this:

```
'foo' . $bar . 'baz'
```

and that regex would match `' . $bar . '`. To get round this, we could write a regex that matches a substring from the start of a line until the first single-quoted string literal that contains `$`:

```
/^(?:[^']|'(?:[^\\']|\\.)*')*'(?:[^'$]|\\.)*[$](?:[^']|\\.)*'/
```

**Caveats:**

- I haven't tested these, so they may not be quite right.
- My PHP is a little rusty, so I'm not sure exactly what string literals are supposed to look like.
- I don't know how you're running the regex; if you're using a regex constructor from a string literal you need an extra layer of character escaping (e.g. in javascript, `/\\/` is equivalent to `new RegExp('\\\\')`).
- You probably have to set a flag, possibly called `m` (again, I don't know what regex engine you're using), so that the initial `^` will match at the start of every line, not just the start of the string; likewise, unset the flag which may be called `s`, since you don't want `.` to match newlines.
- There may be some obscure case I haven't thought of. It's theoretically possible there might be a code comment containing a case you don't want to replace.